# Generating all unique crossword puzzle grids

Tags: crossword

I want to generate all unique crossword puzzle grids of a certain grid size (4x4 is a good size).  All possible puzzles, including non-unique puzzles, are represented by a binary string  with the length of the grid area (16 in the case of 4x4), so all possible 4x4 puzzles are represented by the binary forms of all numbers in the range 0 to 2^16.

Generating these is easy, but I'm curious if anyone has a good solution for how to programmatically eliminate invalid and duplicate cases. For example, all puzzles with a single column or single row are functionally identical, hence eliminating 7 of those 8 cases.  Also, according to crossword puzzle conventions, all squares must be contiguous. I've had success removing all duplicate structures, but my solution took several minutes to execute and probably was not ideal. I'm at something of a loss for how to detect contiguity so if anyone has ideas on this it'd be much appreciated.

I'd prefer solutions in python but write in whichever language you prefer. If anyone wants, I can post my python code for generating all grids and removing duplicates, slow as it may be.

Comment: Are squares allowed to "clump together"?  E.g. is 65535 (all squares used) a valid 4x4 grid?

Comment: @douplep: That's defintely a valid grid. I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean, though -- the contiguity rule means that all valid grids *must* clump together.

Comment: Another question: is single column the same as single row.  I.e. are two grid that are rotation/reflections of each other the same or not?

Comment: Those would be duplicates per the original post:  
> all puzzles with a single column or single row are functionally identical, hence eliminating 7 of those 8 cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: mostly untested other than all tests *do* have an impact by filtering out some grids and a few spotted errors were fixed.  Can certainly be optimized.

```
def is_valid_grid (n):
    row_mask = ((1 << n) - 1)
    top_row  = row_mask << n * (n - 1)

    left_column  = 0
    right_column = 0

    for row in range (n):
        left_column  |= (1 << (n - 1)) << row * n
        right_column |= 1 << row * n

    def neighborhood (grid):
        return (((grid   & ~left_column)  << 1)
                | ((grid & ~right_column) >> 1)
                | ((grid & ~top_row)      << n)
                | (grid                   >> n))

    def is_contiguous (grid):
        # Start with a single bit and expand with neighbors as long as
        # possible.  If we arrive at the starting grid then it is
        # contiguous, else not.
        part = (grid ^ (grid & (grid - 1)))
        while True:
            expanded = (part | (neighborhood (part) & grid))
            if expanded != part:
                part = expanded
            else:
                break

        return part == grid

    def flip_y (grid):
        rows = []
        for k in range (n):
            rows.append (grid & row_mask)
            grid >>= n

        for row in rows:
            grid = (grid << n) | row

        return grid

    def rotate (grid):
        rotated = 0
        for x in range (n):
            for y in range (n):
                if grid & (1 << (n * y + x)):
                    rotated |= (1 << (n * x + (n - 1 - y)))

        return rotated

    def transform (grid):
        yield flip_y (grid)

        for k in range (3):
            grid = rotate (grid)
            yield grid
            yield flip_y (grid)

    def do_is_valid_grid (grid):
        # Any square in the topmost row?
        if not (grid & top_row):
            return False

        # Any square in the leftmost column?
        if not (grid & left_column):
            return False

        # Is contiguous?
        if not is_contiguous (grid):
            return False

        # Of all transformations, we pick only that which gives the
        # smallest number.
        for transformation in transform (grid):
            # A transformation can produce a grid without a square in the topmost row and/or leftmost column.
            while not (transformation & top_row):
                transformation <<= n

            while not (transformation & left_column):
                transformation <<= 1

            if transformation < grid:
                return False

        return True

    return do_is_valid_grid

def valid_grids (n):
    do_is_valid_grid = is_valid_grid (n)
    for grid in range (2 ** (n * n)):
        if do_is_valid_grid (grid):
            yield grid

for grid in valid_grids (4):
    print grid
```

Comment: this looks great! i'm working on refactoring it now so i can print out all of the valid, unique grids to give it a human check. i don't have the karma yet but i would upvote this if i could.

Comment: I think you could upvote even now.  Anyway, it's not quite correct, unfortunately.  The test for contiguosness is broken.  I will edit with correct test if I can come up with one.

Comment: it did come up with some uncontiguous results, but is it also filtering out valid grids? for my purposes, i **can** screen out some of the invalids by hand but i can't add in those which were arbitrarily deleted

Comment: this looks great now, but it seems to be missing a few valid grids... for instance, a grid with one square.

Comment: Are you sure?  With the later fixes `is_valid_grid (4) (0x8000)` evaluates to `True` here.  Choosing topmost row/leftmost column was probably not the best thing to do.  I guess you could switch that for bottom row/rightmost column, then grid 1 should become valid.  Note that switching should be done in three places now: variable defitions, base grid test and after transformation test (plus transformation shifts).

Comment: there should be one valid variation with all but one square blacked and one valid variation with only one black square, but i only see one of these two variations..

Comment: oops! i wasn't looking at your very latest revision. nicely done. thanks a million! now i have to rack up some more karma just to give some to you =]